# Adding Static Dictionary data into my static array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Hi I have prepared static dictionary with data like Like

```
{ Age = 25, Name = Ajay;}
```

My requirement is I want to add this dictionary into My Array, I need a format like

```
({ Age = 25, Name = Ajay;})
```

My Code:

```
mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dictMain =  [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// dictMain = @{ @"Name" :  @"Ajay", @"Age" :  @"25" };

[dictMain setValue:@"Ajay" forKey:@"Name"];
[dictMain setValue:@"25" forKey:@"Age"];
[self dictMain];
```

Comment: [mainArray addObject: dictMain];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this like so:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ @{@"Name": @"Ajay", @"Age": @"25"} ];
```

This will give you an immutable array with the data you want. Note though, that I would use @25 for your age (which will give you an NSNumber), instead of @"25", which will give you a string.

And if you really need to return a dictionary of an array of a dictionary, then you can do:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{ @[ @{@"Name": @"Ajay", @"Age": @"25"} ] };
```

Comment: Thanks Joel  finally i need to return dictionary like {({ Age = 25, Name = Ajay;})}

Comment: dictionary --> arry-->dictionary like this

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: i didn't understand sry

Answer (score 1):

Add `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dictMain = @{ @"Name" : @"Ajay", @"Age" : @"25" };
[mainArray addObject: dictMain];
```

Update:

```
NSDictionary *dictMain = @{ @"Name" : @"Ajay", @"Age" : @"25" };
NSArray *mainArry = @[dictMain];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key" : mainArry};
```

Comment: Why use mutable data types if the data is static?

Comment: finally i want put this array into dictionary can you tell me how